# SQL error in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get Total number of my count column in SQL Oracle but I keep getting THE error:

`ORA-00907 missing the right parenthesis`

Can anyone help me to fix this error?

Here is my query:

```
select isnull(s.years, 'Total') as Grade, count(*) as cnt1, c.firstname, c.lastname
from(
    Select s.years, SUM(count(*) as cnt1), c.firstname, c.lastname
    from employees cc 
    inner join building1 c on cc.id = c.bldid
    inner join members s on s.id = cc.id  
    where sec.LastName = 'Cook'
    group by s.years WITH ROLLUP, c.firstname, c.lastname
    order by s.years, c.firstname, c.lastname
    ) as cnt
```

Comment: Replace `SUM(count(*) as cnt1)` with `SUM(count(*)) as cnt1`?

Comment: Then I'm getting error: missing keyword

Answer (score 2):

In ORACLE you can not use ISNULL use COALESCE and remove alias name inside SUM

```
SELECT coalesce(s.years, 'Total') AS Grade, count(*) AS cnt1, c.firstname, c.lastname
FROM (SELECT s.years, SUM(count(*)) AS cnt1, c.firstname, c.lastname
    FROM employees cc 
    INNER JOIN building1 c on cc.id = c.bldid
    INNER JOIN members s on s.id = cc.id  
    WHEREsec.LastName = 'Cook'
    group by s.years WITH ROLLUP, c.firstname, c.lastname
    order by s.years, c.firstname, c.lastname
    ) as cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select isnull(cnt.years, 'Total') Grade, count(*) as cnt1, cnt.firstname, cnt.lastname
from(
Select s.years, SUM(count(*)) as cnt1, c.firstname, c.lastname
from employees cc 
inner join building1 c on cc.id = c.bldid
inner join members s on s.id = cc.id  
where sec.LastName = 'Cook'
group by s.years WITH ROLLUP, c.firstname, c.lastname
order by s.years, c.firstname, c.lastname
) cnt  --you have to use this to reference columns in the outer query
```

You are selecting from an inner query named `cnt`. You should use it to reference columns in the outer query.

Comment: Still does not work for me. I'm still getting the error: missing keyword

Comment: try casting cnt.years as char like `isnull(to_char(cnt.years), 'Total') as grade`

Comment: Ok I got this to work finally, what I did is in SELECT I use NVL(to_char(s.years),'Total') as Years  and in group by I just use rollup for years value. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

c. has to be replaced with cnt.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your alias from inside the `SUM`.

```
SELECT isnull(s.years, 'Total') AS Grade, count(*) AS cnt1, c.firstname, c.lastname
FROM (SELECT s.years, SUM(count(*)) AS cnt1, c.firstname, c.lastname
      FROM employees cc 
      INNER JOIN building1 c ON cc.id = c.bldid
      INNER JOIN members s ON s.id = cc.id  
      WHERE sec.LastName = 'Cook'
      GROUP BY s.years WITH ROLLUP, c.firstname, c.lastname
      ORDER BY s.years, c.firstname, c.lastname) AS cnt
```